# Can't see google drive docs on Nexus 7

Tags: google-drive

I've installed Google Drive on my pc and Nexus 7 and placed a Google Spreadsheet doc into the drive on my pc. When I use my pc browser (Firefox) to view the googledrive.com website, the doc is there.

However, when I open Drive on my Nexus - nothing. And when I view the googledrive.com website on my Nexus browser (Dolphin) it's empty too. Not a doc in sight.

I'm getting nowhere with Google Help on this issue - they keep telling me to click on options that don't exist on the Nexus or telling me to do things on my android phone (Don't have one!)

Help? Thanks!

ETA: Okay, I've decided what I wanted to do just isn't worth the hassle of trying to figure out Google's accounts/apps systems. It seems designed to be as obstructive as possible. :P I've given up and deleted Drive.

Thanks for your attempts to help though - greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Drive set to sync with your device? `Settings | Accounts | Google | {your Google Account} | Drive` checked? Have you done a sync?

Comment: Yup. Last sync 9.03 this evening.

Comment: Probably an unnecessary question, but you confirmed you're using the same account in both places?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that one. Definitely same account.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. With 2 Nexus 7s, one didn't sync and the other did.

The Google drive app seems to be the curlpit. After uninstalling and reinstalling Drive sync started working properly.